# Groovy - Type checking in script not working as expected

Tags: groovy, type-conversion, typechecking

I have a `Groovy` application in which I allow the user to add custom behavior via `Groovy` scripts. I include those scripts via `GroovyShell` and type check them via `Type Checking Extensions`. The full code of how I include the script in my application is:

```
def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(TypeChecked)
)
def shell = new GroovyShell(config)
shell.evaluate(new File("path/to/some/file.groovy"))
```

This works fine. **However**, type checking in the script seems to be seriously broken. For example, I can include the following scripts **without** any complaint from the compiler:

```
String test = getTestValue() // automatic conversion from Integer to String. But WHY?
println "The value is $test" // shows as "The value is 0" on the console

private Integer getTestValue(){
    return 0
}
```

I can even go further than that. When creating a `class` inside the script, I can assign it to a `String` without any error:

```
String y = new Test()
println y // shows Test@somenr on the console

class Test { }
```

Other type checks **do** work. I have not discovered any logic behind it yet, so any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt, disasm.  This is the bit around a call similar to yours: `String x = new T()`:

```
   0: invokestatic  #17                 // Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
   3: astore_1
   4: aload_1
   5: ldc           #40                 // int 1
   7: aaload
   8: ldc           #42                 // class T
  10: invokeinterface #46,  2           // InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callConstructor:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  15: invokestatic  #52                 // Method org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling.castToString:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  18: checkcast     #54                 // class java/lang/String
```

So [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling.java#L42) is the culprit for that cast.  This seems also to hold true for `@TypeChecked`/`@CompileStatic`.

Comment: @TypeChecked/@CompileStatic is supposed to give a compile time error, if the cast most likely will not succeed.  WeSt did not give a Groovy version so the bug could have been fixed already

Comment: @cfrick That's a really interesting finding you have there, thanks a lot. I had a couple of minutes to test and it really seems that any class is converted to `String` without the compiler giving an error. I'll test a bit more tonight, but if that holds true, I can't help but wonder why I didn't stumble across that sooner. There needs to be some mentioning in the docs at the very least.

Comment: @blackdrag I am using version 2.4.3. Not the newest but fairly new.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot that there are certain cases that always work. String and boolean/Boolean are such cases. So sorry for the noise

Comment: @WeSt Getting doc changes into groovy is rather painless. Go ahead!

Comment: @cfrick Where would you suggest? In the explanation to @TypeChecked/@CompileStatic? Or should I open a ticket (if that is considered an error/ unwanted behavior)?

Comment: @WeSt if in doubt, open a ticket.  The friendly folks will guide you. My _guess_ here is, that it's wanted behaviour, but might lack some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in the Static Type Checker. When LHS of the expression is a String variable, a conversion invoking `ShortTypeHandling.castToString()` is applied to the RHS.

This holds true as of Groovy 2.4.13.