# Groovy - Type Checking with generics not working

Tags: groovy, typechecking

This is a follow-up to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861827/groovy-type-checking-in-script-not-working-as-expected). I import `Groovy` scripts via `GroovyShell` to my application and set the `TypeChecked` transformation. However, static type checking does not work when paired with a class with generic types. The way the following `Groovy` script raises compile-time errors is not obvious to me:

```
Integer x = (new Test<Integer>(5)).value // works as expected
Integer y = (new Test<Object>(new Object())).value // throws a COMPILE error as expected
Integer z = (new Test(new Object())).value // throws a RUNTIME exception

class Test<T> {
    T value

    public Test(T value){
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

The last assignment (`Integer z = ...`) **does not** throw a compile-time error but rather fails at runtime with a `GroovyCastException`. Does anyone know of this behavior or has some pointers to the relevant parts of documentation? So far, I have not found anything. Furthermore, my understanding is that `Test<Object>` and `Test` (without generic parameter) should be treated equally?

## Update

I am using `Groovy` version **2.4.3** and prepared an online script at [GroovyConsole AppSpot](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5171067207286784) to show the inconsistencies on static type checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a bug. I tried a different example with raw and generic ArrayLists. I get the same behaviour.

```
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

@TypeChecked
class Test {

    static method() {
        ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList rawArrayList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        integerArrayList << 1;
        rawArrayList << new Object();
        objectArrayList << new Object();

        Integer x = integerArrayList.get(0);    // Case 1: works as expected
        Integer y = rawArrayList.get(0);        // Case 2: doesn't throw a compile error but should
        Integer z = objectArrayList.get(0);     // Case 3: throws a compile error as expected
    }
}
```

I filed a bug report. See [TypeChecked Groovy does not throw illegal assignment error at compile time when using raw generic type](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7690). Let's see what comes out.